# conditional block in nginx configuration apparently not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I need to add CORS headers to a virtualhost in my nginx configuration.
I'd like to display headers only under certain conditions, but I can't make work my if block appropriately.
I'd expect the headers inside the if block to be always added, but no headers are added, including the one outside the if block.
Here is my configuration:

```
    location /images/ {
            fastcgi_pass    localhost:9000;
            fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
            fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING $query_string;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
            fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
            fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param   HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
            set $cors "test";
            set $mytest "true";
            add_header 'Test2' "$mytest";
            if ($cors = "test") {
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
              add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
            }
   }
```

Comment: I'm calling the resource from openseadragon viewer in a web page and I'm inspecting the network calls through the network inspector in the chrome browser. I've just noticed that if I try to open the resource pasting the url in the address bar, the headers inside the if block are added, but the one outside the if block is not added. When openseadragon calls the same resource I get a 301 error and none of the headers are added.

Comment: And if you change `if ($cors = "test")` to `if ($cors != "test")` you'll see that the headers outside the if block are added. [`if` is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). The only directives that can be safely used inside the `if` block are that from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).

Answer (score 1):

What you can do instead is to use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive substitutions:

```
map $cors $cors_origin {
    "test"  "$http_origin";
}
map $cors $cors_credentials {
    "test"  "true";
}
map $cors $cors_methods {
    "test"  "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
}
map $cors $cors_headers {
    "test"  "Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With";
}

server {
    ...
    location /images/ {
        fastcgi_pass    localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
        set $cors "test";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_origin always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' $cors_credentials always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' $cors_methods always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' $cors_headers always;
    }
}
```

If the `$cors` variable would have any other value than `"test"`, result of `map` substitution will be an empty string, and nginx would not set the corresponding header at all.